# Python requests by session id

Tags: python, session, python-requests, postman, authorization

I have 2 different urls, one for getting an session id, other one is for requesting (post/get) with the session id obtained via first url. When I use postman for that, everthing works fine but in case of python requests, obtained sessionID does not recognized by requests to second url.

How can I overcome this problem? What is the differences between the postman requests and python requests?

If session ID obtained via postman and used in python requests, it works fine also. However the session ID obtained via Python does not working  neither in python and postman.

Comment: Are there headers that need to be included? As Postman autogenerates some headers. https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/#autogenerated-headers

Comment: I included hidden postman headers to my python request but this did not solved my problem

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 2):

were you using python requests? If yes, Use requests' session.

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.post("<your htttp url>", <post params>)
session.get("<your http second url>")
```

Requests session takes care for sending back sessionid if it is in cookies.
If it is a separate header.  You should check for `response.status_code`. usually python requests packager will not create error.

```py
print(response.status_code)
# mostly you are getting session_id but response status code is not 20X for first request
```

Use [dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code).